# Update go-client with OpenAPI generator

Tags: go, openapi-generator, hivelocity.net

I try to  update https://github.com/hivelocity/hivelocity-client-go

I updated the generator version in the Makefile to `6.2.1`, but I get this error message at the end:

```
...
...
go build github.com/hivelocity/hivelocity-client-go/client
go test ./...
# github.com/hivelocity/hivelocity-client-go/client/test
client/test/api_account_test.go:13:2: local import "./openapi" in non-local package
FAIL    github.com/hivelocity/hivelocity-client-go/client/test [setup failed]
?       github.com/hivelocity/hivelocity-client-go/client       [no test files]
FAIL
make: *** [Makefile:17: client] Error 1
```

The generated code looks like this:

```
/*
Hivelocity API

Testing AccountApiService

*/

// Code generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech);

package client

import (
    openapiclient "./openapi"
```

There is no openapi directory or package.

How could this get fixed?

Here is my fork: https://github.com/guettli/hivelocity-client-go

The only thing I changed was in the Makefile:

```
-GENERATOR_VERSION=4.3.1
+GENERATOR_VERSION=6.2.1
```

If I run `make` above error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error is solved in this [PR](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/13905)

```
-    {{goImportAlias}} "./openapi"
+    {{goImportAlias}} "{{gitHost}}/{{gitUserId}}/{{gitRepoId}}{{#isGoSubmodule}}/{{packageName}}{{/isGoSubmodule}}"
```